# Can't Execute Binary on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, bash, perforce

I am attempting install & configure Ubuntu on a machine. I just downloaded `'p4'` (*aka Perforce command line client*).  It's a single file download that is executed via a statically-linked executable binary, there for I downloaded it using the following:

```
wget http://www.perforce.com/downloads/perforce/r09.2/bin.linux26x86/p4
```

That dumped it right into the macines ***`/usr/bin`*** dir.

> *Simple enough, right?*
>
> Except...

```
root@aj-ubuntu:/usr/bin# ll p4 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 748808 2010-02-11 16:54 p4
root@aj-ubuntu:/usr/bin# ./p4 
-su: ./p4: No such file or directory
root@aj-ubuntu:/usr/bin# /usr/bin/p4 
-su: /usr/bin/p4: No such file or directory
```

**What is happening here...?!**

Comment: Change the title Dude.. :-\

Comment: @Bibhas - fair enough.

Comment: Update: Just to be sure, please confirm you are running a 32-bit Ubuntu.
If you are running a 64-bit system, you probably need the 'ia32-libs' package. tks for the tip u just save me from 8 hours of pain in hell :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got the file from your URL (its under 800KB) and tried this (from a Cygwin terminal which was handy).

> $ file p4
>   p4: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

But, you expect it to be statically linked, Why?

---

Update: Just to be sure, please confirm you are running a 32-bit Ubuntu.
If you are running a 64-bit system, you probably need the '`ia32-libs`' package.

Comment: @nik - see my note to @gbjbaanb below.  I tried 'ldd' and all it said was: " not a dynamic executable."  So, I assumed it was statically linked.

Comment: confirm, that's what `file` gives on my system as well.  i don't have a running Linux system available at the moment so i can't check `ldd`.

Comment: @nik - your update nailed it.  i am running 64-bit ubuntu but the binary was built for 32-bit architecture.  i installed ia32-libs and that fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try `file ./p4` and see what it says. Chances are you don't have the right libraries installed to run it (so it cannot load the binary at all - you get the same issues with Windows if you don't have the right dlls)

Comment: @gbjbaanb - I tried 'ldd' and all it said was: "    not a dynamic executable."  I didn't know about 'file' though...I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Do `ls -lb p4*` to see if there are any stray characters in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when your executable isn't valid, it might be for another architecture or for another kernel. Or just a corrupted ELF header.

Answer (score 1):

The intepreter `readelf -a /usr/bin/p4 | grep interpreter` points to is probably missing. It's probably shipped in some compat package as pointed out by other commenters.

Comment: output: `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]` ...

Answer (score 1):

chmod +x /usr/bin/p4

Answer (score 0):

static executable is not dependent of libraries.... it needc a compatible kernel, namely one that has same system calls as it was built on.

p4 is a perforce client, and yours is built against kernel v2.2.5 10 years ago...

it will work with (long unsupported) later 2.2 kernels,

it may work with (month since unsupported) 2.4 kernels,

it will not work with (still supported) 2.6 and 3.x kernels

They make version for 2.6 clients http://www.perforce.com/downloads/complete_list available for your needs.